# How do I deploy a SharePoint custom timer job?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-timer-job

This is what I have done so far:

- Created a class that has my overridden Execute function
- Added the needed strongly named assemblies to the GAC
- Created a Feature.xml file (see it below, this could be the problem...)
- Created a folder for my Feature.xml file in `Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE`
- Used stsadm to `installfeature`.  It says the operation was completed sucessfully.

I then check into Manage Farm Features  in SharePoint but I don't see it there...

Here is my Feature.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" 
   Id="b9e40341-32ab-410a-a20f-282cf13fb54b" 
   ReceiverAssembly="SharePointSocialNetworking, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,   PublicKeyToken=6264b0911592ad29" 
   ReceiverClass="SharePointSocialNetworking.FeatureToEnableJob" 
   Scope="Site" 
   Title="SharePoint Social Networking Job">
 </Feature>
```

Does this look right?  Am I missing any steps here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your scope is wrong. It should be "Farm" not "Site."

Comment: Awesome, that got rid of my first error.  Now i'm getting `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`  Could this be because I used a random guid for my ID?

Comment: @Abe no, a nullreferenceexception is coming from your code. Without being able to see it, noone here can help.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to get stsadm to give me a stack trace along with the error?